# Type annotations needed for String when using AsRef

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'm using Warp like this:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct State {
    topics: HashMap<String, Topic>,
}

struct Topic {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    items: Vec<String>,
}

fn with_state(state: Arc<Mutex<State>>) -> impl Filter<Extract = (Arc<Mutex<State>>,), Error = std::convert::Infallible> + Clone {
    warp::any().map(move || state.clone())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(State::default()));

    let survey = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path!("survey" / String))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(with_state(state.clone()))
        .and_then(|topic: String, state: Arc<Mutex<State>>| async move {
            let state = state.lock().unwrap();

            let topic = state.topics.get(&topic).ok_or(warp::reject::not_found())?;

            let res: Result<Value, Rejection> = Ok(json!({
                "name": topic.name,
                "items": topic.items.iter().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect::<Value>(),
            }));
            res
        })
    ...
```

If I compile it gives this error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed for `std::string::String`
   --> src/main.rs:210:20
    |
210 |         .and_then(|topic: String, state: Arc<Mutex<State>>| async move {
    |                    ^^^^^ consider giving this closure parameter a type
    |
    = note: cannot resolve `std::string::String: std::convert::AsRef<_>`
    = note: required by `std::convert::AsRef::as_ref`
```

This is really weird. What does it mean `consider giving this closure parameter a type`? Doesn't it already have a type? Even weirder, if I comment out this line:

```
            "items": topic.items.iter().map(AsRef::as_ref).collect::<Value>(),
```

Then it compiles! Even though that line apparently has nothing to do with the `topic` parameter. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I just figured out it wanted me to change this:

```
AsRef::as_ref
```

to this:

```
AsRef::<str>::as_ref
```

The error message is just totally wrong.